# Jquery Wordpress javascript split error inside console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do have a problem with my split function, it's throwing a error see image:
[error inside console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtKYc.png)

Hidden Input field inside php file:

```
<input class="file-id" name="_file-id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr($file_ids); ?>" />
```

I saved already values inside it see image:
[values inside hidden input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rbYW.png)

Code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var savedIds = $('.file-id').val();
    var savedIdsArr = savedIds.split(',');

    for(i = 0; i < savedIdsArr.length; i++) {
        savedIdsArr[i] = parseInt(savedIdsArr[i]); 
    }

    console.log(savedIdsArr);

});
```

[img(savedIdsArr)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwHsv.png)

if i do watch the console my code is working fine but it still's show me the error of the split function.
   Hopefully someone can explain it to me and knows the solution.

Comment: Is the function running after the document is ready?

Comment: no it's not running after or in it ?

Comment: Maybe the `<input>` element is created dynamically.

Comment: Titus do you mean to get it from my php file and include it inside my js file the input field?

Comment: It can't really be working fine _and_ be giving an error, even if you're adding the input after the page has loaded because that would require you running that jQuery again and it's not in it's own function - it simply runs once when the DOM is ready.

Comment: (You can simplify that loop with the following, btw: `var savedIdsArr = savedIds.split(',').map(Number);`).

Comment: I mean that `savedIds` can only be `undefined` if there is no elements on the page with the class `file-id` and since you're using `jQuery(function($){....})` is more then probable that `<input class="file-id" .../>` is added to the DOM dynamically.

Comment: nice one andy thanx. getting crazy because of this error

Comment: i tried almost everything i know that it is something small, even if i delete all my code and leave the split inside it's showing the same error only when it's outside the jQuery(function($) { } it's not throwing a error

Comment: [I can't reproduce the error](https://jsfiddle.net/17o4wb8m/4/), so something else must be going on.

Answer (score 1):

you cann't use split() over javascript array . Split is a string function.
If you are directly getting ids in savedIds(here), iterate it you will get one by one values as required

Comment: first of all the saveIds.val() is giving my a output like 505,506 without quotes or anyting it's not even an array. i'm making a array of it see the code.

Comment: @Santosh, the value from the hidden input will always be a string.

Comment: declare  var savedIdsArr =[]; savedIdsArr.push(savedIds) . Now you can iterate it

Comment: if you see anything inside " ",  then split() will work . as it's predefined function of string

Comment: remove   var savedIdsArr = savedIds.split(','); this line

Comment: santosh the code is working fine no problems with that but it's showing me a error inside the console about that split that's the problem sir.

Comment: if you convert   savedIds=  savedIds.toString(); then use split ()

Comment: use var savedIdsArr= [savedIds]; //replace  var savedIdsArr = savedIds.split(',');

Comment: Santosh now it's sayin toString is undefined

Comment: it's like javascript functions are throwing errors?

Comment: i hope this javascript code will be inside your<script> </script> tag .

Comment: in wordpress we use enqueque

Comment: gonna try it from mozilla